# Incremental update of millions of records, indexed vs. join

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra, apache-pig, bigdata, full-table-scan

I'm currently developing a strategy for an incremental update of our user data. We assume  100_000_000 records in our database of which approximately 1_000_000 records are updated per workflow.

The idea is to update records in a MapReduce job. Is it useful to use an indexed storage (eg. Cassandra) to be able to access current records randomly? Or is it preferable to retrieve data from HDFS and join new information to existing records.

The record size is O(200 Bytes). The user data has a fixed length but should be extendable. The log events have a similar but not equal structure. The number of user records is likely to grow. Near real-time updates are desirable, ie. a 3 hour time gap is not acceptable, few minutes is OK.

Have you made any experiences with either of these strategies and data of this size?
Is the pig JOIN fast enough? Is it a bottleneck always to read all records? Is Cassandra able to hold this amount of data efficiently? Which solution is scalable? What about the complexity of the system?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your requirements first. Your record volumes are not a problem, but you don't give a record length. Are they fixed length, fixed field number, likely to change format over time? Are we talking 100 byte records or 100,000 byte records? You need an index on a field/column if you wish to query by that field/column, unless you do all your work using map/reduce. Will the number of user records stay at 100mill (1 server will probably suffice) or will it grow 100% per year ( probably multiple servers adding new ones over time).

How you access records for updating depends on whether you need to update them in real-time or whether you can run a batch job. Will updates be every minute, or hour, or month?

I would strongly suggest you do some experimenting. Have you done any testing already? This will give you a context for your questions and this will lead to more objective questions and answers. It is unlikely that you can 'whiteboard' a solution based on your question.